Unterstanding the result of viewshed analysis QGIS - "depth below horizon"
I would like to know how much I can still see of a wind turbine 10 km (point shapefile) away from my observer point (point shapefile).
I created the viewpoint with QGIS:
observ_hgt: 1,64m /
target_hgt: 280m /
radius: 10000m /
azim_1: 170 /
azim_2: 260
After that, I used the viewshed tool in QGIS. Since I wanted to know whether I could still see 50 meters or just 10 meters of the wind turbine's tip from my observer point, I selected the "depth below horizon" option. But how should I interpret the result?
The raster tile (pixel) where the wind turbine is located shows an elevation of 581m in the DSM and the created raster (using "viewshed" tool and option "depth below horizon") 483 m. The difference is 98 m. What does this mean? Does it imply that a 280 m-high wind turbine would be visible for 98 m or does it mean that 98 m of the wind turbine would not be visible? Or is it something else? Maybe I am completly wrong - also with the settings?

I think you are using the Visibility Analysis tool https://landscapearchaeology.org/qgis-visibility-analysis/ because the GDAL based viewshed tool does not have a "depth below horizon" option.
The documentation https://landscapearchaeology.org/qgis-visibility-analysis-manual/ says:

Depth below horizon will provide the depth at which lay invisible
portions of a terrain. The value produced by this module can be
understood as the theoretical height a construction should attain in
order to appear on the horizon, as visible from the chosen observer
point.

By the documentation I interpret that "depth below horizon= 483 m" means that if you had a 483 meters high turbine you could see the tip of it.
The image in https://landscapearchaeology.org/2018/depth-below-horizon/ seems to support this interpretation.

With this tool I believe that you could use 1,64m as observer height, 0m as target height. The turbine is visible when depth below horizon is less than 280, and formula (280 - depth_below_horizon) will tell how much of the turbine is visible.
All this is based on reading the documentation, I have never used that tool myself.

Yes, thanks. It's exactly what I wanted. Actually, I used the tool with target = 0m and target = 280m (had the same idea). I can now use the raster calculator and would have a result for those areas. I used the formular "280 - depth_below_horizon_result_0m_target" and it worked.
